# Why is only index.html available from an S3 bucket served by CloudFront, and nothing else?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I am trying to expose a static site hosted in S3 though CloudFront.

**The S3 bucket** (`testyop1`) is set to host static websites (not in public mode) and its bucket policy is

```
{
    "Version": "2008-10-17",
    "Id": "PolicyForCloudFrontPrivateContent",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "1",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::cloudfront:user/CloudFront Origin Access Identity E...."
            },
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::testyop1/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

The website hosting configuration states that `index.html` is the index document.

**On the CloudFront side**, the Origin Domain Name is set to `testyop1.s3-website-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com` without any Origin Path. The name has been taken from the S3 web hosting configuration (without the `http://`).

I can access `https://xxxxx.cloudfront.net`, as well as `https://xxxxx.cloudfront.net/index.html` (where xxxxx is the name generated by CloudFront)

All other calls to `https://xxxxx.cloudfront.net` fail with

```
403 Forbidden

Code: AccessDenied
Message: Access Denied
RequestId: F...D
HostId: i...V4X7l4=
```

despite `.html` files being present (both in the root directory and in a subdirectory).

Does that error message come from S3? (or CloudFront?)

**What specific authorizations beyond the Bucket Policy above should be set?**

Comment: You can't combine an Origin Access Identity with the website hosting feature.  OAI is for REST only.  Your objects have to be publicly accessible in order to use the website endpoint behind CloudFront.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot: thank you, following your comment I disabled hosting and recreated the origin from the suggestion in CloudFront. It now works (I also selected, in CloudFront, to restrict bucket access. If you could turn your comment into a reply I would be glad to accept it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't combine an Origin Access Identity with the website hosting feature. OAI is for REST only. Your objects have to be publicly accessible in order to use the website endpoint behind CloudFront, because [website endpoints don't support authentication](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/WebsiteEndpoints.html).

Comment: While your answer is very much correct, I now realized that CloudFront cannot handle bare URLs - that is `http://example.com/hello/` which should open `http://example.com/hello/index.html` (also relevant: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=314454)

Comment: I ended up using https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/implementing-default-directory-indexes-in-amazon-s3-backed-amazon-cloudfront-origins-using-lambdaedge/ and after several ups and downs the solution works (the Lambda must be in `eu-east-1`

Comment: Lambda@Edge functions go in `us-east-1`.  From there, they replicate out to all other regions.